# EE3 Convert Field Type

Tags: fieldtype, ee3

Can anyone confirm that in EE3 once a field has been created, you can't change the field type?

Ellis Lab, is this a feature yet to implemented, or data management perspective no longer a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been filed as a bug, and Derek Jones gives some explanation in the comments there: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/21302/field-type-not-changeable-after-creation

Comment: thanks. I always thought switching field type is very dangerous, especially in a system where anyone can create any field type as an extension. thanks for the heads up.